# How to dismiss Tooltip after second click

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently using a toolTip. When i click on my imageview icon, i would like to show a tooltip. When i click second time on my imageview Icon, it will dismiss the tooltip. And if i click on my imageview the third time, it will prompt the icon and dismiss and show and dismiss. How can i achieve this ?

```
private Tooltip test;

stockToolTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //First Click Will Show the tip
                test = new Tooltip.Builder(stockToolTip).setText("Please Enter the number of stock you have now").show();
                if(!test.isShowing()){

                }
                else{
                    test.dismiss();
                }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `ToolTip` early on and choose whether to show/dismiss them in `onClick` on the imageView.

```
private Tooltip test = new Tooltip.Builder(stockToolTip).setText("Please Enter the number of stock you have now");

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Odd clicks will show the tooltip
                if(!test.isShowing()){
                    test.show()
                }
                else{
                    test.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```